# Forcing SnakeCaseNamingStrategy doesn't work in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, json.net, snakecase

I'm trying to force both serialization and deserialization to use **SnakeCaseNamingStrategy** but no luck.

Here is what I have used in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
protected void Application_Start() {
  AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
  GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
  FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
  RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
  BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

  HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
  config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings {
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver {
      NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
    }
  };
}
```

I even tried it like the following:

```
[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.SnakeCaseNamingStrategy))]
public class RegisterBindingModel {
  [Required]
  [Display(Name = "Email")]
  public string Email { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
  [DataType(DataType.Password)]
  [Display(Name = "Password")]
  public string Password { get; set; }

  [DataType(DataType.Password)]
  [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
  [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
  public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Newtonsoft.Json version: 13.0.0.0

**Update:** the value for "ConfirmPassword" is always `null` when sending data with the key "confirm_password".

Comment: What goes wrong? What's the error or unexpected behavior?

Comment: @LukeVo - I've updated my question, please see the end of the question.

Comment: Does it work correctly when you try setting manually `[JsonProperty("confirm_password")]`?

Comment: @LukeVo - Unfortunately not, it doesn't work either way.

Comment: So that means the problem is somewhere else. How are you deserializing it?

Comment: Also apparently [`NamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_NamingStrategy.htm) only works for **serializing** and not deserializing. You still have a problem though because if `JsonPropertyAttribute` is not working, something is not right with the deserializer. Are you sure Json .NET is being used?

Comment: @LukeVo - How can I make sure if Json.NET is being used by default? It might be using another deserializer, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to confess that the problem was on my behalf and everything works as expected.

I was sending `text/plain` to the API from Postman. And the other mistake was that I was expecting MVC controller to use JSON.NET as deserializer in `ModelBinder` which it doesn't use that so obviously it ignores my `[JsonProperty()]` annotations and even custom configurations in `WebApiConfig.cs` or `Global.asax.cs`.

It should be noted that: Only `ApiController` uses JSON.NET as json serializer/deserializer in its ModelBinder.